# What is the purpose of the & in this struct call?

Tags: c

I am having trouble understanding what the purpose of the `&` means in this if statement. Would anyone be willing to point me in the right direction? I thought struct calls go as follows

```
car -> model == "jeep"
```

This is what I am having confusion about:

```
if ((x->status & 1) == 0){
...
}
```

Comment: It is a bitwise and operation.

Comment: So it would & status in this case? For instance, with the care model if there was a call 
if((car -> model & jeep) != jeep) {
return 1;
}

Comment: `car -> model == "jeep"` note that this is wrong. Learn C strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((x->status & 1) == 0){ ... }
```

This code retrieves the value of the `status` field from the struct pointed to by `x`, and performs a bitwise and operation against the constant 1, which has the effect of masking off all but the least significant bit. As a result, this code is checking whether the least-significant bit of the field's value is zero.

Comment: Thank you so much, this clears up so much : )

Answer (score 1):

This

```
if ((x->status & 1) == 0){ ... }
```

Is same as

```
unsigned status = x->status;
unsigned status_bit0 = status & 1;
if (status_bit0 == 0) { ... }
```

And single `&` with two operands (on both sides) is bitwise AND operator, not to be confused with unary `&` which is address-of operator and completely unrelated. Learn binary numbers to understand what bitwise AND is and how it can be used to extract a single bit, that's too broad a subject for this answer.

Also note that `unsigned` may be wrong type, use what ever is the type of the strict field.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much, this does make it more clear : )